# Is it possible to have UNIQUE on the date portion of the datetime field?

Tags: mysql

I have a website where the URL contains the year, the month, the date, plus the permalink generated from the article's title. For example

```
www.example.com/1999/12/31/techno-party
```

But since the publishing time for articles needs to be per hour, not just per date (e.g. you are able to set the publishing time at 12:00 or 13:00 during the day), that means the publish time column in the database needs to be of `datetime` datatype, not just `date`. That means I could then have an article with the permalink `techno-party` that is being published on December 31st at 12:00, and another (with the same permalink) that is being published on the same day at 13:00 (duplicated created by another user, or by mistake, irrelevant), and their URL's would end up being the same.

So in order to avoid duplicates in this scenario, I need a UNIQUE index for the permalink string, the month, the date, and the year. But obviously, if I set the UNIQUE index on the `permalink` column and the `datetime` column, I can still have a lot of duplicates, because the would only restrict them from being published the same exact second.

In theory what I need is a UNIQUE index on the year, month, and date values from the `datetime` column (ignoring the hour/minute/second) + the `permalink` column. But is such a thing possible from the database level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to store separately date and time.

Otherwise, you can try adding a ("hidden") DATE field and a trigger.

```
create trigger setArticleDate BEFORE INSERT ON article 
     for each row set NEW.__date = DATE(NEW.publish);
```

Then you create a UNIQUE on permalink and __date.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a function-based index, which is not supported in MySQL. (See PostgreSQL [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-expressional.html) to get the idea).

As a workaround, you could add a separate indexed column for the date portion and populate it with insert and update triggers.